# Php nestedfor loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have an array in php, and I want to print the elements of the array, 15 at a time, from (n-15). Like, if I have 100 elements in an array, I want to print it 85-100,70-84,55-70,, etc.,

I've tried the loop

```
 for( $j = sizeof($fields)-16; $j < sizeof($fields); )  {
 for ( $i = $j ; $i < $i+16 ; $i++  ) {
 echo $fields[$i];
 echo "<br>";
 }
 $j=$j-16;
 }
```

but, this prints only the first iternation, i.e 85-100, and goes into an infinite loop.

Where am i going wrong?
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.3, you can do this:

```php
<?php
$fields = range(1, 100);

foreach (array_chunk(array_reverse($fields, true), 15, true) as $i => $chunk) {
  echo 'Group ' . $i . ":<br/>\n";
  $chunk_rev = array_reverse($chunk, true);
  array_walk($chunk_rev, function($value) {
    echo "$value<br/>\n";
  });
}
```

See the [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DvTPPq).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (array_reverse(array_chunk($fields, 15)) as $chunk) {
  foreach ($chunk as $field) {
    echo $field . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Chunking is perfect, but how do i achieve the printing from n-15 to n and so on?

Comment: This is the inner iteration, or what is the question? What is `n`? Updated: Did I get it right, that you want the last chunk to processed first? I've added `array_reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the loop termination condition.

If $j is being decremented and $j starts off lower than the comparison value, $j will never be greater than the comparison value, so the loop will never terminate.